# Как запустить проект python на физическом ip?

Tags: python, flask, веб-сервер, ip, localhost

Сделал проект на Python (Flask), на своем компе по этому ip 127.0.0.1 я могу посылать запросы. Есть физический ip 192.168... Мне нужно посылать запросы с другого компьютера моему приложению. Я прочитал,  что можно запустить проект на физическом ip.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Точно 192.128, а не 192.168?

Comment: поправил, но не суть

Comment: что значит "физический ip"? почему вы решили, что 192.168... более физический, чем 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два варианта на выбор:

```
Запуск с передачей аргумента:
flask run --host=192.168.0.1

Запуск в коде:
app.run(host="192.168.0.1")
```

Также надо иметь разрешающие правила брандмауэра или стороннего Firewall.

Comment: вдобавок к брандмауэру и файрволу можно было упомянуть ещё один синоним — [межсетевой экран](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD).

Comment: Можно и не упоминать